# PM2 not starting node.js app in multiple instances

Tags: node.js, pm2

Both of these each work to start my app:

```
node app
pm2 start app.js
```

The following does not work (app not working but PM2 status shows 2 instances online) and does not log any errors:

```
pm2 start app.js -i 2 --watch -l log/log.log
```

Launching with the following process.json file also does not work (but PM2 status still shows 2 instances online)  and does not log any errors:

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "app",
    "script"      : "./app.js",
    "instances"   : 0,
    "exec_mode"   : "cluster",
    "watch"       : true,
    "ignore_watch"  : ["tmp","public","images_review"],
"error_file"      : "./logs/error.log",
"out_file"        : "./logs/out.log",
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
  }]
}
```

Launching in fork mode with the following process.json file still does not work but does log an error.

```
{
  "apps" : [{
    "name"        : "app",
    "script"      : "./app.js",
    "instances"   : 0,
    "watch"       : true,
    "ignore_watch"  : ["tmp","public","images_review"],
"error_file"      : "./logs/error.log",
"out_file"        : "./logs/out.log",
    "log_date_format"  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",
  }]
}
```

The error it logs is "Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000". I checked and nothing is using port 3000. I also switched my node.js app to use a different port and it still gives an EADDRINUSE error for every port I try. I'm on a 2 core linode with Centos 7 running Plesk Onyx. What's going on that I'm missing?

Comment: What does `app.js` do?

Comment: It is an express app.

Comment: It's to be expected that you get that error when using fork mode: cluster mode allows multiple processes to use the same port but fork mode doesn't, so the second process that gets started will get the error because the first process is already listening on :3000. I assume that with _"does not work"_ you mean you can't access port 3000 after pm2 started?

Comment: Ah good to know.

Comment: I have figured out why my app doesnt work i  cluter mode. I did not add logs directory to the ignore_watch so it pm2 would loop logging and restarting due to watching the logs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try running it with

```
pm2 start app.js -i 0 -l log/log.log
```

Which makes pm2 use the maximum number of cores available

Then you can view your logs in real time using

```
pm2 logs
```

Comment: Running without watch worked. I needed to add logs directory to ignore_watch or else pm2 will continually restart due to watching the logs.

Comment: Glad you could get around that. :). I never use `--watch` myself. I prefer to restart the process when I'm done editing my code.

Comment: I think you log something in a file and so because you watch everything, your server restarts again and again

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved with **PM2 version** somehow.

*Issue :* With version 3.0.3, it did not work in cluster mode.
However, when ***downgraded PM2 version to 3.0.0***, it worked.

Agree with @robertklep's comment though.

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the default process using "pm2 delete all" Worked for me!!

the default process that needs to be deleted:
[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).